# DDD End Runs, application layer calls to another that is not directly below it

Tags: model, architecture, domain-driven-design

There is an image in Evans DDD book that shows a UI acessing different layer of application.

[DDD Evans book image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO9M2.png)

According to Steve Smith in his Pluralsight 'n-tier design' course:

"An end run is when one application layer calls to another that is not directly below it. End runs like this destroy the advantages of utilizing an N-tier application design resulting in an application with all of the disadvantages and complexity of an N-tier design and none of its advantages."

In the same Pluralsight, Smith in his course "Fundamentals of DDD" make some controllers accessing repository (infra) directly, making a controller act like some kind of application service coordinating repository access and domain objects.

My question is:
The image Evans book demonstrates is that in DDD one are not restricted to follow a specific layered architecture FLOW but instead, take advantage of different layers to protect the domain and make the code cleaner. We are free to access different layers of application directly if it suits our requisites, the restriction is that we keep the Domain concerns restricted to the Domain to protect our model?

This image represent a correct DDD approach?

[Is this correct in DDD?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFy9j.png)

Comment: Not at all. The domain layer will never have a direct dependency to anything on infrastructure, this is no useful design

Answer (score 0):

[image]

> This image represent a correct DDD approach?

I would call it an *acceptable* approach.  In 2003, when Evans wrote the first [ddd](/questions/tagged/ddd) book, layers were understood to be the best practice at the time -- a sort of separation of concerns, if you will.

More recently, the trend has been away from layers.  See, for example, this presentation by [Udi Dahan](https://vimeo.com/113515335#t=19m06s).

> How can I prove to you that these layers are tightly coupled to each other...?
>
> Who -- when the business came to them and asked them to add another column to a given field -- had to touch more than one layer in their code base?

The important idea isn't "layers", but instead making sure that the domain logic is cohesively organized.

For example, if your application is reaching around the domain model to change the underlying data correctly, that's not so good.  If the application is reaching around the domain model to *read* the underlying data -- that may not be such a big deal (see [cqrs](/questions/tagged/cqrs)).

The "layered" approach gets further confused  when you look into the onion architecture, or ports-and-adapters.

My current take is that clean layers are optimized for the case where you are commonly re-grafting your layers into different implementations.  My experiences are that those cases are not particularly common; and therefore the investment odds are lousy compared to approaches that make it easier to extend the design.